# How would i restart StreamWriter onced it has been used?

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I am using a Streamwriter method for a button click to run a test, but after the test is complete I want to run it again and record the results in the same text file.

I always receive an error that the file is still in another process even though the previous test has been completed. I have tried using .Close() but then I get a "Can't write to closed textwriter" error message.

```
 StreamWriter ResultsFile = new StreamWriter(FileName, true);

    public void ToFile()
    {
        ResultsFile.AutoFlush = true;
        Console.SetOut(ResultsFile);
        Console.WriteLine("Regression Test Performed at {0}", thisDate);
        Console.WriteLine("-----");

    }

   [Test]
    public void NewTextFile()
    {
        ToFile();
        const int requiredNumber = 5;
        for (var i = 0; i < requiredNumber; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("New ID assigned to ABC");
            Console.WriteLine("-----");
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not reuse the `StreamWriter` like that, try the following instead.

```
public void ToFile(StreamWriter sw)
{
    sw.AutoFlush = true;
    Console.SetOut(sw);
    Console.WriteLine("Regression Test Performed at {0}", thisDate);
    Console.WriteLine("-----");
}


[Test]
public void NewTextFile()
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(FileName, true))
    {
        ToFile(sw);
        const int requiredNumber = 5;
        for (var i = 0; i < requiredNumber; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("New ID assigned to ABC");
            Console.WriteLine("-----");
        }
    }
}
```

Explanation of `using` can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx). I would also advise you to read about [`IDisposable` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx).

Beware that after exiting the `using` statement, calling `Console.WriteLine` would result into `ObjectDisposedException` as you would be trying to write into disposed stream. To prevent this situation you can cache the return value of `Console.Out` into local variable before entering the `using` statement and after exiting the using statement you can restore the state by again calling the `SetOut` with cached value of original stream, i.e.:

```
var original = Console.Out;
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(FileName, true))
{
    // ...
}
Console.SetOut(original);
```

Comment: Even though I am using the 'using' keyword, I am still getting an error that StreamWriter has been closed. I was under the impression that with the 'using' keywoard a new sw object is created each time.